# Why assign a declared function to a variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, closures

I'm trying to learn about closures and came across this bit of code from MDN. I tried it in jsbin and it works, but I can't figure out why it's necessary to assign makeFunc to var myFunc and then calling myFunc rather than just calling makeFunc, which doesn't work.

```
function makeFunc() {
    var name = "Mozilla";
    function displayName() {
        alert(name);
    }
    return displayName;
}
var myFunc = makeFunc();
myFunc();
```

Comment: `makeFunc()();` works. Or if you change the `return` to `return displayName();`, `makeFunc();` would then work.

Comment: *"rather than just calling makeFunc"*  But you are calling it in `var myFunc = makeFunc();`. Not sure I understand what you are confused about.

Comment: @FelixKling they seem to not understand why simply calling `makeFunc()` does not trigger the alert. Or at least that's my guess.

Comment: "doesn't work" is certainly not a useful problem description, because your expectation of how it "should work" is probably completely different than ours. But we cannot really help you if you don't explain your perspective.

Comment: yes. you can leave myFunc away. Simply do makeFunc()();

Comment: You are basically describing 'Partials'. You are having a function that returns another function. A example of using this would be to use a templating library such as Underscore or Handlebars. The first function call would be something like this `var myTemplate = template('<div>{{name}}</div>')` to set the template. And the second call would be to pass the data to retrieve the HTML: `var html = myTemplate({ name: "some name"});`

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion, but Patrick was right about what I meant by "doesn't work."

Answer (score 4):

> I can't figure out why it's necessary to assign makeFunc to var myFunc

That isn't what is happening. Look at the code:

```
var myFunc = makeFunc();
                     ^^
```

`makeFunc` is being **called**. It is its **return value** that is assigned to `myFunc`.

That return value is `displayName` (which has access to the closed over `name` variable).

`myFunc();` then calls *that* function.

Answer (score 1):

`makeFunc` is returning a function called `displayName` which includes the value of "Mozilla" within the variable `name` which is only accessible within the `displayName` function (although it doesn't "know" that it was originally called "displayName"...it just simply now contains the body of that function along with the value of `name`). When you assign the result of calling `makeFunc` to `myFunc`, `myFunc` contains the function `displayName`, including the value of `name`. Note, however, that `displayName` has not yet at that point in time been called/invoked. Now, when you invoke `myFunc`, `displayName` is run, creating an alert showing the name "Mozilla".

Answer (score -1):

I'll try to give a very short answer:

`makeFunc()` only returns the function without executing it because the return value is the name of the function.

```
var myFunc = makeFunc();
myFunc();
```

From the code above you're assigning the function that I previously mentioned to `myFunc`. On the next line you add a `()` which means execute the function. Hence why you see the `alert();` result.

---

#### Illustration

```
makeFunc() == displayName
myFunc == makeFunc()
myFunc == displayName
myFunc() == displayName()
```

Answer (score -2):

On page load closure allows a function to run automatically

> FOR YOUR CODE --  you can re-adjust your code to this like you anticipated without assigning it to variable myFunc

```
(function makeFunc() {
    var name = "Mozilla";
    function displayName() {
        alert(name);
    }
    return displayName;
})();
```